# Saving image data as a byte[] in MSSQL through EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

The column is a `varbinary(MAX)` called `Data`. I generated an ADO.NET model from the existing database to use with EntityFramework.

Creating a new model, I set the field as follows:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(filename);
var model = new Media();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
model.Data = ms.ToArray(); // the model field is of byte[] type

db.Media.Add(model);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The final line, `db.SaveChanges()` will throw a `DbEntityValidationException` stating: `Data must be a string or arraytype with max length '5000'`.

When I step through the code, I find that my sample image (972x355, 71,6 kB) results in a `byte[73571]` value for `model.Data`. Is this too large for the db column? What can I do differently to allow the database to store this image?

I use similar code in a different project, which works just fine. The only difference there is that I insert the image through a stored procedure. The stored procedure doesn't do anything to the parameter, it just plain inserts it.

Comment: you must have some problem with your model configuration. The feld is `varbinary(MAX)` in your DB, but your model has something that makes it think it's `varbinary(5000)`. Look for some configuration related to that column. I do insert files in a varbinary field directly with EF, i.e. without stored procedures, without any problem

Comment: @JotaBe you were correct: for some reason updating the ADO.NET model does not pull all changes from the database. I recreated it and it runs fine now with the field correctly set to `varbinary(MAX)`.

Answer (score 2):

In your model for media you can add the typename Image if your column in database is an image, if you use varbinary(MAX) you can just use `byte[]` normally.

```
public partial class Media
{
   //[Column(TypeName = "image")]
   public byte[] Data {get; set;}
}
```

Also you can get the bytes much easier:

```
model.Data = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

By the way if your `Media` model is used for other things than fetching the image, you should make a separate model for storing the image data and make a one-to-one relation to `Media`. That way you don't have to fetch the whole image everytime you need a `Media` model.

Comment: The column type is `varbinary(MAX)` indeed. However, @JotaBe's comment solved it for me. Thanks for the tip on reading the bytes, though, that helps.